# Queue Not Found when using MassTransit SendEndpoint to Send a message

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, masstransit

I see the following exception on app start, when using a SendEndpoint on Azure Service Bus. Cannot reproduce the issue on RabbitMQ; cannot reproduce on ASB when using `Publish()` instead of `Send()`.

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: Queue was not found
  at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.QueueDescriptionExtensions.ParseFromContent(String xml) in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\Management\QueueDescriptionExtensions.cs:69
  at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient.GetQueueAsync(String queuePath, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\Management\ManagementClient.cs:198
```

Following the stacktrace, `queueName` it's complaining about in [`GetQueueAsync()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/e7dc3b48c8037ee9cd04a428e454088f082e1d8c/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/Management/ManagementClient.cs#L190) is `GaldinsMac_dotnet_bus_dpfoyyr5d1ojub5kbdmqijse8g`.

It's a simple console application. Here's my code:

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(sbc =>
    {
        sbc.RequiresSession = false; // doesn't seem to help
        var host = sbc.Host(
            "Endpoint=sb://ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=localtesting;SharedAccessKey=key", 
            _ => { });
    });

    try
    {
        await bus.StartAsync();
        // the exception is thrown here, but I can still continue and ignore the exception

        var uri = new Uri(bus.Address, "queueName");
        // debugger shows uri to be: sb://ns.servicebus.windows.net/queueName

        var endpoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(uri);
        await endpoint.Send(new SayHiCommand(
            name: "Jane Doe"));
    }
    finally
    {
        await bus.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

The code works with RabbitMQ but not with ASB, so I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere. Works with ASB if I use `Publish<>()` instead of `Send<>()`, but that's not what I want here.

Comment: If that queue is not found, it should create it. If you don't have Manage permissions on your service, it will fail to start.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson the SAS token has all permissions (manage, listen, send). The app with the consumer uses the same SAS token, and is able to create queues.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out last week. The code is fine, like Chris stated in the comments.

1. Silly typo with the queue name. Which explains why it worked with `Publish<>()` but not with `ISendEndpoint.Send<>()`. It worked with RabbitMQ because a consumer with the typo-ed queue-name was running locally.
2. The exception only occurs when debugging. Something to do with Rider's Debugger and .NET SDK 2.2.300